# What is the name of this property of a complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Consider matrix $H \in \mathbb{C}^{2n \times n}$. Since the matrix is tall there always exists nonzero $z \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ such that $z^\top H = 0$. However, if the square matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{Im}\{H\} & \operatorname{Re}\{H\}\end{bmatrix}$$ is nonsingular then there does not exist nonzero $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $\lambda^\top A =0$, and thus $\lambda^\top H \ne 0$ for all $\lambda \ne 0$.

Is there any common name for this property? If not, then what is a good way to say this? I am considering "the columns of $H$ are linearly independent on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$", but that does not sound good.

Comment: Well, you can say that your columns are $\textit{really}$ linearly independent..

Sorry..

Comment: One thing we can say is that $\ker(A^T) \cap \Bbb R^{2n} = \{0\}$; $\ker(A^T)$ is sometimes called the "left nullspace" of $A$.